# how can i perform the update

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net

its update command

```
protected void btnGuncelle_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    
        string sorgu = "UPDATE PersonelBilgileri set Ad=@Ad,Soyad=@Soyad,DogumTarihi=@DogumTarihi,Telefon=@Telefon,TcNo=@TcNo,Maas=@Maas,GirisTarihi=@GirisTarihi,CikisTarihi=@CikisTarihi WHERE PersonelID=" + Application["PersonelId"].ToString() + "";
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand();
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Ad", txtAd.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Soyad", txtSoyad.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@DogumTarihi", txtDogumTarihi.Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Telefon", txtTelefon.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@TcNo", txtTcNo.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Maas", txtMaas.Text);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@GirisTarihi", txtGirisTarihi.Value);
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@CikisTarihi", txtCikisTarihi.Value);  
        Class1.EkleSilGuncelle(cmd,sorgu);
        Response.Redirect("WebForm1");        
        
    }
```

its EkleSilGüncelle

```
 public static void EkleSilGuncelle(SqlCommand cmd, string sql)
    {

        SqlConnection baglanti = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["StajConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        baglanti.Open();
        cmd.Connection = baglanti;
        cmd.CommandText = sql;
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        baglanti.Close();
        cmd.Dispose();
        baglanti.Dispose();
    }
```

the code that allows the selected data to come to this screen

```
 int id = int.Parse(Application["PersonelId"].ToString());
        Class1.KayitGetir(txtPersonelID, txtAd, txtSoyad, txtDogumTarihi, txtTelefon, txtTcNo, txtMaas, txtGirisTarihi, txtCikisTarihi,id);
```

this KayitGetir

```
 public static void KayitGetir(TextBox PersonelID, TextBox Ad, TextBox Soyad, HtmlInputGenericControl DogumTarihi,TextBox Telefon,TextBox TcNo,TextBox Maas, HtmlInputGenericControl GirisTarihi, HtmlInputGenericControl CıkısTarihi, int personelId)
    {
        SqlConnection baglanti = new SqlConnection("Data Source = ; Initial Catalog = ; User ID = ; Password = ");
        baglanti.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from PersonelBilgileri where PersonelID='"+personelId.ToString()+"'", baglanti);
        SqlDataReader dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while(dr.Read()){
            PersonelID.Text = dr[0].ToString();
            Ad.Text = dr[1].ToString();
            Soyad.Text = dr[2].ToString();
            DogumTarihi.Value = ((DateTime)dr[3]).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            Telefon.Text = dr[4].ToString();
            TcNo.Text = dr[5].ToString();
            Maas.Text = dr[6].ToString();
            GirisTarihi.Value = ((DateTime)dr[7]).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
            CıkısTarihi.Value = ((DateTime)dr[8]).ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
        }
        dr.Close();
        cmd.Dispose();
        baglanti.Close();
        baglanti.Dispose();   
    }
```

When I select it in the table and press update The data I selected appears on the screen, but when I change the data and press update, the operation does not take place.
i don't know if i explained it fully,sorry for my bad English

Comment: When you `SELECT` you put the `PersonelID` in quotes. When you `UPDATE` you don't. You should use a parameter here too, though. [And better not use](https://www.dbdelta.com/addwithvalue-is-evil/) `AddWithValue`.

Comment: Debug your code. Set a breakpoint and step through the code line by line, to see if, where and how its behaviour differs from your expectations. You ALWAYS need to provide this debugging information when you post a question. If you actually do the debugging, you'll likely not have to ask the question, or maybe something else more specific.

Comment: If `ExecuteNonQuery` actually is executed then you need to catch the return value and see what it is, because it indicates whether and how many database rows were affected.

Comment: @John I tried debugging line by line but
nothing wrong or missing

Comment: @theenes I would prefer to hide IP information in your code. Anyway, what you mean by screen ? I see the SQL query but not a screen.

Comment: If you debugged and everything worked exactly as you expected then there are two possibilities. Either everything is working correctly and you are unable to see that for some unknown reason, or there is something amiss with your expectations. To be sure, did `ExecuteNonQuery` get called and, if so, what value did it return?

Comment: @ahmetgül When I run it, after I select the line, I press the update button, the information comes, the information is not updated after I change the information and press update

Comment: Is this older code? If you are starting a new project I would suggest using the Entity Framework.

Comment: Side notes: You have SQL injection at `where PersonelID='"+personelId.ToString()+"'`, use a parameter instead.  You should have a `using` on the connection, command and reader objects.

Comment: @John same value comes

Comment: That's not answer to my question. ExecuteNonQuery returns a number. What is that number?